# I kill the Airflow task, but its subprocess, created by its BashOperator, haven't been killed

Tags: airflow

My Airflow has a task that uses BashOperator to run pySpark script on our server. I kill the Airflow task from UI, and the task itself can be killed. But its subprocess, created by its BashOperator, haven't been killed, and is stilling running on our server.

I think it might be an issue that some signal like “Stop” is not be transferred correctly from my Airflow task to the pySpark process.

```
`BashOperator(
    task_id=task_name,
    bash_command=bash_command,
    env={
        'PATH': '{{ PATH }}',
        'PYSPARK_PYTHON': '{{ PYSPARK_PYTHON_PATH }}',
        'PYTHONPATH': '{{ HOME }}/python-lib'
    },
    dag=dag
)`
```

Could you help me find how to solve this problem?